# How to make txt, csv and pem files read and writable only by root with sudo previliges?

Tags: command-line, permissions, chmod

I have some files inside a folder with various formats like `.txt`, `.pem`, `.csv` and `.json`.
I want only sudo/root to be able access them. I have done

```
chmod 700
```

and

```
chmod 600
```

on each of those files. But, I can still print the private key of my `.pem` files by doing `cat` on terminal without sudo privileges and open `.json` files from the file system in "gedit".

What has gone wrong? How do I not let anyone access the contents of those files?

Comment: please post the output of the command `ls -l`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your file is named `example.txt`. Then:

```bsh
$ sudo chown root: example.txt
$ sudo chmod o-rwx example.txt
```

should do the job.

If you want an entire directory `exampledir` to be accessible only to root:

```bsh
$ sudo chown -R root: exampledir
$ sudo chmod -R o-rwx exampledir
```

Comment: How to also undo it? I mean to say, remove those restrictions and make them accessible to not root user too?

Comment: If your username is `student`: `sudo chown -R student: exampledir`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the owner of the file is root and set the permissions.
Eg filename 'test.txt'
Run the following command

```
sudo chown root:root test.txt 
sudo chmod 700 test.txt
```